# Remove a particular character and newline using sed

Tags: sed

Say I have text:

```
Abc
B\
CH
DEG
```

It should be

```
Abc
BCH
DEG
```

Only new lines preceded by backslash should be removed, together with the backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -z 's/\\\n//' file
```

Consume file as one line (-z) and then substitute \ and a new line for nothing,

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e :a -e '/\\$/N; s/\\\n//; ta' myFile
```

Comment: I believe this answer is correct, however further explanation of the steps involved would likely benefit OP and any future readers of this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `\` is always followed by a newline, you can shorten [Raman Sailopal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65723007/5825294) by 1 character:

```sh
sed -z 's/\\.//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/\\\n//;P;D' file
```

Open a 2 line window and remove `\\n` between 2 lines.